# animation hide/show only occurring once

Tags: ios, ios6, uipicker

im trying to do an animation on UIPicker where when my app runs its hidden and when the button is pressed it will appear sliding from the buttom and when i tap the button again it will slide away. well, my code does that but only just once. 
it does:

first click -> show the picker, isPickerHidden = NO

second click -> hides picker, isPickerHidden = YES

third click -> does not do anything, but it returns isPickerHidden = NO
where in viewDidLoad declaration are;

and same as the fourth click it doesnt do anything but return the correct BOOL value.

```
isPickerHidden = YES;

[self.picker setHidden:isPickerHidden];

if(isPickerHidden == NO){
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
        CGRect frame = self.picker.frame;
        [self.picker setFrame:CGRectOffset(frame, self.picker.frame.origin.x, self.picker.frame.origin.y)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        isPickerHidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"hidden yes");
    }else if(isPickerHidden == YES) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
        CGAffineTransform transfrom = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -200);
        self.picker.transform = transfrom;
        [self.picker setHidden:NO];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        NSLog(@"hidden no ");
        isPickerHidden = NO;
    }
```

i would like to know on whats the problem i am facing, and what am i missing. thanx

Answer (score 0):

add some logging for the frame and picker to see what is happening...

```
    NSLog(@"picker: %.0f, %.0f, %.0f, %.0f", self.picker.frame.origin.x, self.picker.frame.origin.y, self.picker.frame.size.width, self.picker.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: i will do and try it.will be back again

Comment: idk what i did wrong but it seems that in every iteration the y-axis value seems to be added by 244. thats what i found out about it.and making some changes too but it doesnt really help. any idea btw?

Comment: that's 200pts from yours plus an additional 44pts from the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

thanx NS bro for the reply but i did a different approach now instead of offsetting the points from the original one i used CGRectMake, i did this

```
if(isPickerHidden == NO) {
        CGRect frame = self.picker.frame;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];

        [self.picker setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y + 216, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        isPickerHidden = YES;

    } else if (isPickerHidden == YES) {
        CGRect frame = self.picker.frame;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];

        [self.picker setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y - 216, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        isPickerHidden = NO;

    }
```

both the sliding down and sliding up are doing well animated in the same manner. but now the problem is i wanted to make the UIPicker disappear on app load so in the viewDidLoad i did try to use the  [self.picker setHidden:YES]; but the frames i made using CGRect dont appear when i press the button and i also tried alpha still nop.

i did also put in the body of the if-else statement the setHidden to yes and to know with respect to their values.
would like to know what im missing now.